# Change SQL Server Express default R library path

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is it possible and if so how to change the default SQL Server Express path for R packages:

`C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library`

to something more pleasant and more manageable as:

`C:/R/library`

Even when I try to install packages to R using R studio:
`install.packages("dplyr", lib = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library")` 
I get a warning:

`Warning in install.packages : 'lib = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library"' is not writable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For R in SQL Server Machine Learning Services, you cannot change the path.

However, from SQL Server 2019 CU3+, you can "bring your own" R runtime, where you then can define where it is located. Doing this you are no longer using the RevoScaleR enabled R, but "normal" R.

Read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/custom-runtime-r

Comment: How do you know I cannot change the path?

Comment: Well, if you could - you'd be able to do it during installation. Don't forget that the R that is installed with SQL Server is "special" - it has special extensions etc. In your post above around installing with RStudio, how are you running RStudio, as a "normal" user, or admin. I must say I have never tried to install R packages to SQL Server R using RStudio. I have always done it from command line. I wrote quite a lot around installing R packages here: https://nielsberglund.com/sql_server_ml_services_install_packages/

Comment: 1. Do you think that the problem might be due to a lack of administrative rights which might restrict /Program Files/ path? 2. Are you sure that during the installation of SQL Server Express I can choose whatever path for SSE itself as well as the R library path?

Comment: Thanks Niels, do you know anything about the two questions I asked in my comment?

Comment: Sorry for not having replied earlier. For 1 - yes, I believe it is lack of admin rights. For 2 - I have not worked with SQL Server Express, so I am not sure. However, even if you can choose the install path for Express itself, you cannot alter where R is installed, as it is installed in subdirectories of SQL.